# SEandroid Boot Up Problems

Tags: android, boot, nexus-7, selinux

I'm currently working on flashing SEandroid (security enhanced Android) onto a Nexus 7, but when I try to boot up, the Nexus 7 just flashes the Google screen and nothing else.

I successfully compiled the SEandroid Source code for both 4.2.1 and 4.1.2 and neither run on the Nexus.

Was wondering what some common errors could be for a device booting up, but the screen not showing anything?

I downloaded and compiled the code according to: http://selinuxproject.org/page/SEAndroid

I am using the tegra3_android_defconfig for my kernel and am using the full_grouper_userdebug.

Any help, even if not related to SEandroid would be helpful.

Here is an output from logcat:

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
I/Netd    (  124): Netd 1.0 starting
W/InterfaceController(  124): Warning (Cannot load library: load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "/system/lib/libnetcmdiface.so" not found) while opening the net interface command library
I/installd(  130): installd firing up
I/DEBUG   (  125): debuggerd: Jun 12 2013 10:32:23
I/SurfaceFlinger(  126): SurfaceFlinger is starting
I/SurfaceFlinger(  126): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing     graphics H/W...
E/libEGL  (  126): eglGetDisplay:121 error 300c (EGL_BAD_PARAMETER)
E/libEGL  (  126): eglInitialize:137 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
```

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rookie mistake. Forgot to add in Google's proprietary drivers for the Nexus 7.

Available here for who ever needs them!

https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers

thanks all